# Error faced when running a server implemented by jetty, jackson

Tags: java, gradle, jackson, jetty

I'm trying to run a server implemented by someone else.

This is the link to the project that I'm trying to run. 
https://github.com/mccorby/PhotoLabellerServer

I followed the instructions given in README.md file of the repository.

1. I created currentRound.json file manually
2. I modified the `local.properties` file under the server module (specified the directory to save the trained model)
3. I succeeded to run the `Main.kt` file that is training an initial model. The trained model was successfully saved in the directory that I specified in the `local.properties` file.
4. Then, I tried to run the `JobQueueServer.java`. The server is successfully started, however, the RestService is not working at all. I tried to check whether the server is up by hitting `http://localhost:9997/service/federatedservice/available`. Then it returns the following error.

Simple error message:

[image: Simple error message]

This is a link to the video showing how I am facing the error. 
https://youtu.be/cQFvegW-JXo

And I will post the full error message at the end of this post.

Based on the error report, it shows that the code `jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(getCurrentRoundJsonFile())` is causing the error.

Error:

```
12:24:48 AM: Executing task 'JobQueueServer.main()'...

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 648 ms
:server:compileKotlin
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /Users/stevejaehyeokkim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.2.41/5e34ca185bbea7452d704ed3537a22314a809383/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.41.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/stevejaehyeokkim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.2.41/7e34f009642702250bccd9e5255866f408962a05/kotlin-stdlib-1.2.41.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/stevejaehyeokkim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.41/d0cfb3ef897c00449e5e696355db9506225fb507/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.41.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/stevejaehyeokkim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.1.3/bfc9458443666b1be1d66813f3a90a03afa30730/kotlin-reflect-1.1.3.jar (version 1.1)
w: Consider providing an explicit dependency on kotlin-reflect 1.2 to prevent strange errors
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-runtime-version-check' to suppress this warning
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /Users/stevejaehyeokkim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.2.41/5e34ca185bbea7452d704ed3537a22314a809383/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.41.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/stevejaehyeokkim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.2.41/7e34f009642702250bccd9e5255866f408962a05/kotlin-stdlib-1.2.41.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/stevejaehyeokkim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.41/d0cfb3ef897c00449e5e696355db9506225fb507/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.41.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/stevejaehyeokkim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.1.3/bfc9458443666b1be1d66813f3a90a03afa30730/kotlin-reflect-1.1.3.jar (version 1.1)
w: Consider providing an explicit dependency on kotlin-reflect 1.2 to prevent strange errors
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-runtime-version-check' to suppress this warning
:server:compileJava
:server:copyMainKotlinClasses
:server:processResources NO-SOURCE
:server:classes
:server:JobQueueServer.main()15 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @257ms
76 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.2.9.v20150224
574 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@27e47833{/,null,AVAILABLE}
588 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@518caac3{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9997}
588 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @840ms
Oct 27, 2020 12:25:11 AM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4134)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3988)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2909)
    at com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.core.datasource.FileDataSourceImpl.retrieveCurrentUpdatingRound(FileDataSourceImpl.kt:80)
    at com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.core.datasource.ServerRepositoryImpl.retrieveCurrentUpdatingRound(ServerRepositoryImpl.kt:29)
    at com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.web.RestService.<init>(RestService.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:777)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:710)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:54)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:129)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.web.RestService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:393)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:777)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:710)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:54)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:129)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


11928 [qtp64830413-24] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - 
javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 0]
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.web.RestService

    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 0]
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.web.RestService

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:392)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:777)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:710)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:54)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:129)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4134)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3988)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2909)
    at com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.core.datasource.FileDataSourceImpl.retrieveCurrentUpdatingRound(FileDataSourceImpl.kt:80)
    at com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.core.datasource.ServerRepositoryImpl.retrieveCurrentUpdatingRound(ServerRepositoryImpl.kt:29)
    at com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.web.RestService.<init>(RestService.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
    ... 47 more
11930 [qtp64830413-24] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - /service/federatedservice/available
javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 0]
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.web.RestService

    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 0]
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.web.RestService

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:392)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:777)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:710)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:54)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:129)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4134)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3988)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2909)
    at com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.core.datasource.FileDataSourceImpl.retrieveCurrentUpdatingRound(FileDataSourceImpl.kt:80)
    at com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.core.datasource.ServerRepositoryImpl.retrieveCurrentUpdatingRound(ServerRepositoryImpl.kt:29)
    at com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.web.RestService.<init>(RestService.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
    ... 47 more
11934 [qtp64830413-24] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - Could not send response error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 0]
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.mccorby.photolabeller.server.web.RestService
```

Comment: Have you tried to open `getCurrentRoundJsonFile()` file and check it's content? Maybe it is an empty file?

Comment: @MichałZiober the content of currentRound.json file is empty. Do you know what should I put in the file..?